# Consuming REST API from the server side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, resteasy, postman

I am going to write a webserver which serves various clients through REST API.
 For example , I have city table which list of all the cities and the URI "/cities" will return all the cities in the CITY database.
 In this case , when "/cities" URI is requested , the backend code will query the database and form JSON and respond.
 There is another module in the server  which requires the same list of cities . Do I need to reuse the same REST implementation in this case or I can directly query the database as this server side query.

Thanks

Comment: You can create a module which manages reading / writing the DB which *both* the REST server code and your separate module use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Making an HTTP request for that data wouldn't be very efficient.

Directly querying the database means duplicating code.

The best approach here is probably to write a module which accesses the database and gets the data and then use that module from both places in the code that need that data.

Comment: Just what I was trying to write in a comment! You certainly put it well :)

Comment: I was thinking the same and Quentin agreed . Thanks . Is this kind of any design pattern?